# Is there a way to kick/ban everyone in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot right now, and I'm following a tutorial for kicking/banning members, however I cant seem to find a way to kick/ban everyone. The current code kicks a specific user:

```
    async def kickall(ctx, member : discord.Member):
        await member.kick()
```

How can I make it kick everyone? Thank you. If you have any questions or ways that I can improve this question, feel free to ask/tell me.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the only way to do that is to kick each member individually. You could maybe try doing kickall and mentioning @everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get members of the guild and iterate through them with a `for` loop:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['kickall'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick_all(self, ctx, reason):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.kick(reason=reason)
            print(f"Kicked {member.name}")
        except:
            print(f"Could not kick {member}")
```

Here is how you would do it since you're not in a `Class`:

```
@client.command()
async def kickall(ctx, *, reason=None):
    if ctx.message.author.top_role.permissions.administrator:
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.kick(reason=reason)
                    print(f"Kicked {member.name}")
                except:
                    print(f"Could not kick {member}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Missing permissions.")
```